# Multithreaded Server receives data from just one client JAVA

Tags: java, android, multithreading, server, datainputstream

I ve created a simple MultiThreaded server. Everytime it accepts client a DataInputStream and DataOutputStream is created and the comunication start

Server:

```
public class Connection implements Runnable{
boolean isAlreadyOpened = false;

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    try {           
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(7000);
        while(true){
            System.out.println("Il Server sta cercando Connessioni");
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("Il Server ha accettato un Client");

            Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){             
                   try {

                        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                        isAlreadyOpened = true;
                        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                        while(true){
                            String test = dis.readUTF();
                            dos.writeUTF(test);
                            System.out.println(test);
                            dos.flush();
                        }                       
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        isAlreadyOpened = false;
                    }  
                }           
            });
            t2.start();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }  
}
```

I ve tried to connect an Android application and a JavaApp; every 40 seconds both of these programs send a string via writeUTF. The connection is established correctly from both Clients but the server receives Data just from the last one that connects to server. 
How can I allow the server to receive/send the data from/to ALL the clients?

EDIT:

I ve tried to set this:

```
public class Connection implements Runnable {

 @Override
  public void run() {

    try {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(7000);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Server is listening");
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("Client Accepted");

            Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                        while (true) {
                            String test = dis.readUTF();
                            dos.writeUTF(test);
                            System.out.println(test);
                            dos.flush();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException 
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            s.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });                 
    t2.start();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But the result is the same

EDIT:

Andorid Client Code

```
public class Connection implements Runnable {
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 7000);
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

        while(true){
           dos.writeUTF("FromAndroid");
            Log.d("InputStreammmm", dis.readUTF());
         Thread.sleep(10000)
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

JAVA APP CLIENT CODE

```
@Override
public void run() {
     try {

        Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 7000);
        System.out.println("Connessooo");
         DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
         DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

         while(true){
         dos.writeUTF("Invioooooooooooooooooooooooooo");
         result = dis.readUTF();
         System.out.println(result);
         Thread.sleep(10000);
         }

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

EDIT WITH LIST OF SOCKET:

```
public class Connection implements Runnable {
List<Socket> sList = new ArrayList<>();
Socket s;
int i = 0;

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(7000);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Server Listening");
            s = ss.accept();
            sList.add(s);

            System.out.println("Accepted Client --- " +s.toString());
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());  

                        while (true) 
                        {
                            String test = dis.readUTF();
                            System.out.println("Message sent from -- " + sList.get(i).toString());
                            System.out.println(test);

                            while(i < sList.size()){
                                 DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(sList.get(i).getOutputStream());
                                 dos.writeUTF(test);    
                                 System.out.println("Message Sent to -- " + sList.get(i).toString());
                                 dos.flush();
                                 ++i;
                             }
                            i=0;
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally
                    {
                        try
                        {                      
                            System.out.println("Closing Socket --- " + sList.get(i).toString());
                            sList.get(i).close();
                            sList.remove(i);

                        }
                        catch (IOException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            t2.start();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Doing in this way my problem is solved as suggested by EJP...

Comment: You're never closing the accepted socket. But otherwise this code should work. Are you sure the problem isn't at the client end? But how does this code compile when `s` isn't final?

Comment: What if the 3 clients connect quickly but don't immediately send data to the server. These variables all go out of scope. Of course this code is not OK.

Comment: @peter.petrov The code will block in `readUTF()` until data is received or an exception occurs. Nothing wrong here.

Comment: @EJP OK, but who keeps reference to `s` and `t2`? Aren't they subject to garbage collection almost immediately? Maybe I am wrong, I just read the code, didn't try anything.

Comment: @EJP I m not closing the socket becasue the server should listen for data from clients.. ClientSide I never close the socket connection.. I simply have a writeutf called everyt tot seconds

Comment: You must close the accepted socket `s` after the loop. The `isAlreadyOpened` variable is pointless: remove it.

Comment: @peter.petrov There's a mystery about why `s` isn't final, but a socket won't be garbage-collected while there are references to it or its streams, and a thread won't be garbage-collected while it's running.

Comment: @EJP I ve tried to put s.close() after dos.flush but it throws immediatly an exception "Socket is Closed".. I can post the Client code if it can help?

Comment: Of course. That's not where I said to put it, but it should be closed in a `finally` block after the `catch`, actually.

Comment: I ve tried also after "dos.flush}" ( I mean outside the while loop) but eclipse says Unreacheble code. I ve tried to declare the Socket outside the thread but it is the same result

Comment: It should be closed in a `finally` block after the `catch`, actually. Not that I'm claiming it will solve your problem. There's no reason to declare the socket outside the thread.

Comment: I ve updated the thread.. is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, but can you please format your code correctly? Very difficult to read like this.

Comment: @peter.petrov OK thanks, well done, clears up that mystery.

Comment: I ve tried to format it a little bit.. probably now is more readable

Comment: @peter.petrov Can we please delete our irrelevant discussion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot reproduce.

Test program, copy-pasted from your edited code and added `final` to `Socket s` as I am using Java 7, and added client code:

```
public class Connection implements Runnable
{

    @Override
    public void run()
    {

        try
        {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(7000);
            while (true)
            {
                System.out.println("Server is listening");
                final Socket s = ss.accept();
                System.out.println("Client Accepted");

                Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                            while (true)
                            {
                                String test = dis.readUTF();
                                dos.writeUTF(test);
                                System.out.println(test);
                                dos.flush();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (IOException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                s.close();
                            }
                            catch (IOException e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                t2.start();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Connection c = new Connection();
        Thread  t1 = new Thread(c);
        t1.setDaemon(true);
        t1.start();
        Runnable    r = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try (Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 7000))
                {
                    DataOutputStream    dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                        dos.writeUTF("Hello from "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        String  reply = dis.readUTF();
                        Thread.sleep(10*1000);
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException|InterruptedException exc)
                {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        Thread  t2 = new Thread(r);
        Thread  t3 = new Thread(r);
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Server is listening
Client Accepted
Server is listening
Client Accepted
Server is listening
Hello from Thread-1
Hello from Thread-2
Hello from Thread-2
Hello from Thread-1
Hello from Thread-2
Hello from Thread-1
Hello from Thread-2
Hello from Thread-1
Hello from Thread-1
Hello from Thread-2
Hello from Thread-1
Hello from Thread-2
Hello from Thread-2
Hello from Thread-1
Hello from Thread-1
Hello from Thread-2
Hello from Thread-2
Hello from Thread-1
Hello from Thread-2
Hello from Thread-1
```

Comment: My code is the same.. but it doesn't work.. Can it be a problem of java8?
Or can it be something related to the difference btween my Clients ( one JavaApp and one Android)?

Comment: Post your clients and I'll tell you.

Comment: Ok I ve figured it out.. My serve now can listen from both Clients.. So the server displays all the messages.. but the Clients Don't receive the message sent by the other one. I m posting the clients code.

Comment: I don't see any reason why those clients won't work. The clients aren't *supposed* to 'receive the messages sent by the other one'. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Yes this is the point.. How can I set the client to be able to receive data also from other Client

Comment: The server will have to *send* it to the other client. So it will need a list of client sockets and traverse them all when a message is received.

Comment: Ok I though it would be this the solution.. I will try to create A Socket[] that storres all clients.. And Inside the loop I should create a for loop that write data(dos.wrtieUTF) to all the Clients inside Socket[].. I will post something when this is done Thanks so much for the help

Comment: I strongly suggest a `List<Socket>` instead of an array. Make sure you clean it up when the accepted socket gets closed.

Comment: Really appreciated.. I will try it.. Thanks really much for your time

Comment: I have updated the code and everything is solved.. But in this way when an exception is thrown My code close every time the first Socket in the list.. How can i understand which socket thrown the exception and close it?